Why can't we build the tangent space with regular vectors instead of derivatives of the curve?
Consider a curve on $n$-dimensional manifold parameterized by $t$. The curve can be represented by a  function $X(t) = (x_1(t), x_2(t), ..., x_n(t))$, where $ t $ is the parameter, and each $ x_i(t)$ is a component function of $t$.
The tangent vector to the curve at a point corresponding to $t = t_0 $ is given by the derivative of $X(t) $ with respect to $t$, evaluated at $t_0$. Mathematically, this is written as:
$$
   X'(t_0) = \frac{d}{dt} X(t) \Big|_{t=t_0} = \left( \frac{dx_1}{dt}, \frac{dx_2}{dt}, ..., \frac{dx_n}{dt} \right) \Big|_{t=t_0}
   $$
This vector $X'(t_0)$ is the tangent vector at the point on the curve corresponding to $t_0 $
Now, on a smooth manifold, I can find patches which are locally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. So if I want to define a displacement vector, I should be able to write $\mathbf{r} = X(t+h) - X(t)$.
Why can't I just use this displacement $\mathbf{r}$ to define a vector space on the manifold that would serve the same purpose as the tangent space for $X'(t)$? Why do I need derivatives of the curve in order to make vectors if we have this local isomorphism?

This makes no sense. The displacement depends entirely on the coordinate chart and has no meaning back on the manifold.

There is a way in which this can be made to work, it is sometimes called the "physics approach" to vectors on manifolds. The problem is, as Ted mentioned, that the vector you get this way is going to change depending on what your coordinate representation of your curve is (choice of chart).
What you can do is define a transformation that converts your vector into "new chart" components when you change charts. Then you define a "vector" to be the equivalence class of all n-tuples that can be transformed into one another under this transformation.
Specifically, if $\phi:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\psi:V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are charts for a smooth manifold M, the transformation used is the linear map $d(\psi \circ \phi^{-1}): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.
